# Python Soap client WSDL functions

Tags: python, web-services, soap, wsdl, zeep

I am trying to create a python soap client with zeep.
But i can't figure out how to use the functions which are defined in the WSDL.

Here is my code:

```
from requests import Session
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
import zeep
from zeep.transports import Transport


session = Session()
session.auth = HTTPBasicAuth('admin', 'ip411')
transport_with_basic_auth = Transport(session=session)

client = 

zeep.Client(wsdl='http://10.8.20.27/pbx10_00.wsdl',transport=transport_with_basic_auth)

client.service.Initialize('soap','test',True,True,True,True,True)
```

You can look at the WSDL here: www.innovaphone.com/wsdl/pbx10_00.wsdl

Comment: On behalf of the tech community, I am sorry you have to still work with SOAP.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.